# How to append `/` at the end of directory names from o/p of find command

Tags: bash

I am using `find /tmp/tartest/ -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -not -type l` command to get a list of all files and directories excluding symlinks. This gives me the following o/p:

```
/tmp/tartest/hi.txt
/tmp/tartest/hello1.txt
/tmp/tartest/testdir
/tmp/tartest/hello.txt
```

Notice `/tmp/tartest/testdir` Is it possible to end this with a `/`? `/tmp/tartest/testdir/` for all directories found?

I am using this o/p in a shell script.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to do this, rather than just using `test -d` (which is a shell builtin, so doesn't incur fork/exec penalty) to check type?

Comment: ...and if you're *sure* this is what you want to do, which version of `find`? Are you 100% certain that you only need to support systems with GNU `find` (as opposed to the BSD version)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`find` expressions can have branching logic. The *default* way two subsequent actions are attached is with `-a` ("and"), but you can also use `-o` ("or") manually.

Thus, with GNU `find` (used here because it supports `-printf`, letting you specify arbitrary format strings):

```
find /tmp/tartest -maxdepth 1 \
  -type d -printf '%p/\n' \
  -o -printf '%p\n'
```

Note:

- `-maxdepth 1` is global, so it applies by nature to all branches.
- `-type d -printf '%p/\n'` prints directory names (content where `-type d` is true) with a `/` after them.
- `-o -printf '%p\n'` attaches to the above with an *or* condition, such that the `printf` with no `/` only runs when something does *not* match `-type d`.

Comment: This printed 2 additional things: `/tmp/tartest/`(The parent directory) and also listed the symlinks

Comment: ok `find /tmp/tartest -maxdepth 1   '(' -type d -printf '%p/\n' ')'   -o '(' -not -type l -printf '%p\n' ')'` this removed the symlinks. Now the only thing left is the parent directory(/tmp/tartest/). Why does that get printed.

Comment: I guess `-o -print` should be suffice

Comment: @aaj, you could also run `find /tmp/tartest ! -type l '(' '(' -type d -printf '%p/\n' ')' -o -print ')'`, so no print is reached when `-type l` is true.

Comment: How would you do this on a Mac where printf is not supported?